# How to get the time span between two date picker values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker, timespan, difference

I've added two Bootstrap Datetime pickers to a HTML5 form. So far I can capture the DateTime value of each picker using the change event of the control.

Now I have a case where the time span difference between both DateTime pickers needs to be stored as a var.

I did come across an example similar to this [ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript). But my short implementation below alerts a value of "Nan" instead of the expected time span difference when the actual time picker value is changed.

[image]

**Question:**

How can you calculate the time span between two date picker values in Javascript or JQuery?

**Code gist:**

```
var start;
var actual;

$("#OutageStartDisplay").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    start = $('#OutageStart').val(moment(e.date).format());
});


//On change of the ActualDisplay datetime picker 
//update's the Actual hidden field with the datetime.
$("#ActualDisplay").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    actual = $('#Actual').val(moment(e.date).format());

    //If the actual is set, calculate the outage duration
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(start - actual);
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
    alert(diffDays);

});
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the values of all your variables after they're set? Perhaps one of them is not of the type you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using moment, you can use [moment.diff](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) to get the time difference.

Your code also seems a bit bugged, when you do `$("whatever").val(something)`, you're setting `"whatever"`s value to `something` and it returns `$("whatever")`, not the value. So you're trying to subtract a JQuery object from another JQuery object. But even if it returned the val, your val is a string - which you also cannot substract.

So you probably want this instead:

```
var start;
var actual;

$("#OutageStartDisplay").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    start = moment(e.date);
    $('#OutageStart').val(start.format());
});

$("#ActualDisplay").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    actual = moment(e.date);
    $('#Actual').val(actual.format());

    //If the actual is set, calculate the outage duration
    alert(actual.diff(start));
});
```

Comment: Ok this seems to output the difference in milliseconds. Is there a cast to output this in hours?

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

You can pass a unit of measurement to moment.diff.

`actual.diff(start, "hours")`

Comment: Ok cool, is there any way I could convert the difference into a Day: HH: MM string or timepspan via JS? example 1 Day, 4 Hrs, 45 MIns

Comment: moment is new to me, it might have a way, but until there's something better, you could just do actual.diff(start, "days") + ": " + actual.diff(start, "hours") etc.